# NodeMCU doesn't seem to set digital pin low

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I'm writing a simple project, using NodeMCU as my board. I have 2 analog devices: moisture sensor and brightness sensor. Since NodeMCU has only one analog pin, I try to power them in turns. To do so, I connect them to digital pins of NodeMCU. Digital pins output 3.3V 20-40mA in `HIGH` state (checked that with multimeter). That must be enough to power those devices. In the `LOW` state, according to Arduino IDE docs, voltage must be 0V (and that also was checked) and the sensor must not receive any current and, thus, must not output anything to A0. However, at the end I get correlated results: if I flash light at the photoresistor, humidity data is also affected. And vice-versa. How can I avoid it?
Here's the code, I'm using to do, what I described:

```c
const int analogInputPin = A0; // Analog 0 (A0) on the board

// Several devices will use the same analog pin to send data
const int lightSensorResultPin = analogInputPin;
const int moistureSensorResultPin = analogInputPin;

const int lightSensorPowerPin = 16;
int lightSensorResult = 0;

const int moistureSensorPowerPin = 5;
int moistureSensorResult = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(lightSensorResultPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(lightSensorPowerPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(lightSensorPowerPin, LOW);

  pinMode(moistureSensorResultPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(moistureSensorPowerPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(moistureSensorPowerPin, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  /*==LIGHT SENSOR DATA READ BLOCK==*/
  digitalWrite(lightSensorPowerPin, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  lightSensorResult = analogRead(lightSensorResultPin);
  digitalWrite(lightSensorPowerPin, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  /*==END OF LIGHT SENSOR DATA READ BLOCK==*/

  /*==MOISTURE SENSOR DATA READ BLOCK==*/
  digitalWrite(moistureSensorPowerPin, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  moistureSensorResult = analogRead(moistureSensorResultPin);
  digitalWrite(moistureSensorPowerPin, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  /*==END OF MOISTURE SENSOR DATA READ BLOCK==*/

  Serial.print("Value on the light sensor: ");
  Serial.println(lightSensorResult); // Light value. Low for bright
  Serial.print("Value on the moisture sensor: ");
  Serial.println(moistureSensorResult); // Moisture value. Low for wet
}
```

**UPD: Here's the schematic**

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Please attach a schematic of your circuit

Comment: @mashuptwice, I've updated the question with schematic

Comment: There's no way this is going to work reliably as pictured. Understand that when one sensor is powered, its signal is also flowing back into the other sensor's output line. The result is going to be messy to say the least. You'd need diodes to prevent current flow back into the two sensors, or a relay to electrically isolate the output of one from the other. You also really shouldn't power devices from GPIO pins; they can only source a small amount of current.

Comment: @romkey, I understand all your concerns. However, my devices do not require high current. 20mA, provided by GPIO in `HIGH` state is more than enough. It's the same as lighting LEDs with GPIO (you actually power them with GPIO.HIGH). Also my devices must NOT be powered at the same time, according to the code. There's no chance to get `HIGH` on both D0 & D1 simultaneously. And readings are done only when that exact sensor is powered. Hence their signals must NOT interfer. However, they do. And I want to understand why. I know about relays solution and will settle with it as soon as I can buy one

Comment: @romkey, If you have any explanation, why, for this exact code and circuiting, readings interfere, please post an answer, and I'll upvote it

Comment: You're misunderstanding how electricity works. It doesn't matter that both devices won't be powered on at the same time. Without protection, current from the output of the first device will flow into the output of the second device. They need to be electrically isolated, and they're not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using digital outputs to switch on and off the different sensors, but combining their analog outputs, I would use an analog switch like [4066](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/4066-quad-bilateral-switch-circuit.php) to select which sensor you want to measure.
[image]

Comment: This way you can keep the sensors powered always, but just measure one output at a time.